# ComboBox.SelectionLength = 0 throws InvalidArgument Exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

For a ComboBox, when I set the SelectionLength = 0, I get the error:

```
InvalidArgument=Value of '-1470366488' is not valid for 'start'.
Parameter name: start
Stack Trace: 
at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.Select(Int32 start, Int32 length)
at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectionLength(Int32 value)
at MyCompany.Odin.WebClient.STComplexView.loadViewFormats()
```

This isn't after a `Clear()`, nor is it a bound control.

The (not-so) interesting things in this code:

```
//Adding Items to the combo box (6 in total)
// ...
viewFormatComboBox.Items.Add(appResMgr.GetString("STR_6X2_HEXAXIAL"));
viewFormatComboBox.SelectedIndex = 2;
viewFormatComboBox.SelectionLength = 0;   //<<<< The exception is thrown here
```

Nowhere in our code do we specify SelectionStart, but it's already got the -1470366488 value when I get to the code I included above. I assume this is used when the ComboBox does a

```
ComboBox.Select(Int32 start, Int32 length)
```

call, triggered by setting SelectionLength. I assume that SelectionStart is used for the start argument and viola, we have the InvalidExceptionArgument show above.

This is in debug code. The style is `DropDownStyle`, everything else looks to be unremarkable, but in the debugger I see that the `SelectionStart` property is -1470366488.

This code has been in place for a couple of years, and I run into this exception today for the first time when testing a debug build. I am selecting the item I want displayed with the SelectedIndex = 2 line, then I get the exception when setting SelectionLength
Any explanations?

Comment: I think the issue is with your interpretation of `Selection` - do you want to select text in the Combo Box, or did you want to `Select` an item?

Comment: Hmm. According to the exception, you're specifying `-1470366488` for the value, not 0. The code that you've shown doesn't actually include the line where you set the `SelectedIndex` property, so I can't tell what is going wrong. `SelectionStart` has nothing to do with `SelectedIndex`; is that possibly the source of the confusion?

Comment: davisoa - I'm trying to ensure that no text is selected in the textbox.

Comment: Cody - See the post for updates, thx.

Comment: davisoa - I fixed the problem in the question, it should make more sense now. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the exception and call stack it looks like the simplest solution would be to insert:

```
viewFormatComboBox.SelectionStart = 0;
```

before

```
viewFormatComboBox.SelectionLength = 0;
```

to ensure that it has a valid value.

Comment: This is what I did, though I'm not sure what changed to surface this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explanation of to what rather than why.

The setter for SelectionLength calls:

```
this.Select(this.SelectionStart, value);
```

The first line checks arg validity

```
 if (start < 0)
      {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("start", System.Windows.Forms.SR.GetString("InvalidArgument", (object) "start", (object) start.ToString((IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)));
      }
```

As you pointed out, your SelectionStart as a value of -1470366488. The question is why? The getter for SelectionStart calls:

```
int[] wParam = new int[1];
System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef((object) this, this.Handle), 320, wParam, (int[]) null);
return wParam[0];
```

Msg 320 (0x140) is CB_GETEDITSEL. According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k27f88h8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), that should return:

> Gets the starting and ending character positions of the current
>   selection in the edit control of a combo box.

Clearly it's not. It's returning -1470366488. Why? Who knows. I would guess CB_GETEDITSEL is returning an error, which is not checked and wParam[0] is undefined and the framework is just blindly using it.

Perhaps explicitly setting SelectionStart (which sends a CB_SETEDITSEL) before setting SelectionLength will minimise the chance it could happen.

Comment: Steven, Nice breakdown - gets closer to the explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a Combo Box Style of DropDownList the Combo Box Control does not really have a 'Text' box entity. So setting that object's SelectionStart or SelectionLength has unpredictable results, as mentioned above. As mentioned in other posts ([Weird behavior caused by using .Net ComboBox properties SelectionStart & SelectionLength in "DropDownList" mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944263/weird-behavior-caused-by-using-net-combobox-properties-selectionstart-selectionLength) , http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/csharpgeneral/thread/80B562C9-981E-48E6-8737-727CE5553CBB ) it is also suggested not to use these properties, I see why. But testing for that style and not setting the Start value fixed our issue.

If Not Me.DropDownStyle.Equals(Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList) Then
    Me.SelectionStart = Me.Text.Length
End If

Hope this helps someone in the future...